# Inject into entity's constructor using API-Platform

Tags: symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

I have the following entities shown below.

When a new `Project` is created, my current approach is to use a doctrine pre-persist listener to do the following, and do similarly with `ProjectUserMember`:

```php
$user = $this->security->getUser(); //Uses JWT in header
$project->setTenant($user->getTenant());
$project->setPermissionPrototype(clone($user->getTenant()->getPermissionPrototype()));
```

Maybe petty but I don't really like this approach since each entity's `$tenant` and `$permission` properties should never be changed and I would prefer to eliminate the setters and inject then in the constructor.

This [symfonycast](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform/serialization-tricks#what-about-constructor-arguments) describes passing values to an entities constructor, however, I think they need to come from the request and not sure if this is appropriate for my need.

How can one inject an entity into another entity's constructor when using API-Platform?

Tenant (Not an ApiResource)

- $id (PK)
- $permissionPrototype (One-to-one to Permission)

Permission (Not an ApiResource)

- $id (PK)
- $someAssociation (Many-to-one to some other table)
- $otherData

User (ApiResource)

- $id (PK identifier)
- $tenant (Many-to-one to Tenant)
- $username
- $password

Project (ApiResource)

- $id (PK identifier)
- $permissionPrototype (One-to-one to Permission)
- $tenant (Many-to-one to Tenant)

ProjectUserMember (ApiResource)

- $id (PK)
- $user (identifier)
- $project (identifier)
- $permission (One-to-one to Permission)
- $tenant (Many-to-one to Tenant)

Comment: @yivi  I don't believe so.  You mean blamable?  Doesn't it use setters just like my solution and not the constructor?

Comment: There is more than one answer on that question, the other one does not use blameable. Also, it's exactly the same issue, even if the answers may not be 100% satisfactory. Note my comments under the "blameable" answer, which echo your concerns.

Comment: @yivi  Ah, you mean use a DTO.  I haven't messed with them yet but agree that using them appears to be a solution.  Still, would have thought there would have been a more direct solution, but oh well.  Thanks and will give it a try.  PS.  I don't think the title of your referenced post will lead others to finding it when trying to inject into an entity's constructor and hope my post isn't closed for no other reason than allowing others to see your comment directing them to it.

Comment: The whole idea about closing a question as a duplicate is to help other users finding the target. The dupes serve as signposts.